# Custom font size for captions

Tags: captions, fontsize

This code is fine:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  font=small,
  labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
  format=plain}
```

But I want to customise my font like this:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  font={\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont},
  labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
  format=plain}
```

The latter code gives a compile error. Help?

Here is a minimal example that includes the code that doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  font={\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont},
  labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
  format=plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the font key as you show takes a name not a fragment of tex code.  (incidentally it's always better to provide a complete test document,helps people to test answers)

Comment: But `whatever`  *is* relevant code ...

Comment: in most classes 10pt is the default size, so what is the intention of `\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont`  other than slightly reducing the line spacing?

Comment: For future reference: Even thought you want to "just show the important parts" in terms of code, those who want to answer the question have to type the surrounding filler anyway, so you might just as well add that content.

Comment: I can give a motivation for his question. The Brazilian National Standards Organization (ABNT) requires all captions to be slightly smaller than the font of the text along the document. I bet that there are similar rules for each country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *define* the new font style, since [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) requires this as part of its key-value input:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFont{myfont}{\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont}

\captionsetup{
  font=myfont,
  labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
  format=plain
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :-D